# Java: cannot access annotations through reflection

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Here is a test class:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class TestAnnotations {

    @interface Annotate{}

    @Annotate public void myMethod(){}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Method[] methods = TestAnnotations.class.getDeclaredMethods();
            Method m = methods[1];
            assert m.getName().equals("myMethod");

            System.out.println("method inspected ? " + m.getName());
            Annotation a = m.getAnnotation(Annotate.class);
            System.out.println("annotation ? " + a);
            System.out.println("annotations length ? "
                + m.getDeclaredAnnotations().length);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my output :

```
method inspected ? myMethod
annotation : null
annotations length : 0
```

What I am missing to make annotations visible through reflection ?
Do I need an annotation processor even for just checking their presence ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In order to access an annotation at runtime, it needs to have a Retention policy of Runtime.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) @interface Annotate {}
```

Otherwise, the annotations are dropped and the JVM is not aware of them.
For more information, see [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html).

Comment: May I ask, though, if you happen to know whether there is a way to change the default behaviour of CLASS retention policy to RUNTIME ?

Comment: Only by recompiling the annotation. If it's not your annotation, no.