# how to get annotations in java through reflection

Tags: java, annotations

this is my annotations:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/trade/createrequisition")
```

now i would like to get request method `it is POST` in this case and the value `it is /trade/createrequisition` in this case.

How to do this using reflection in java.

Please help me to resolve this.

EDIT:

this is what is my actual method :

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#request, 'CREATE_REQUISITION')")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/trade/createrequisition")
    public @ResponseBody
    void createRequisition(@RequestBody CreateRequisitionRO[] request,
            @RequestHeader("validateOnly") boolean validateOnly) {
....
}
```

this is how i tried to get the @RequestiMapping:

```
package com.hexgen.reflection;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI;

public class WebAPITest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class<HexgenWebAPI> clazz = HexgenWebAPI.class;
            Method methodAnnotaion = clazz.getMethod("createRequisition");
            RequestMapping methodRequestMappingAnnotation = methodAnnotaion.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
            RequestMethod[] methods = methodRequestMappingAnnotation.method();
            String[] mappingValues = methodRequestMappingAnnotation.value();

            for(RequestMethod req : methods){
                System.out.println("RequestMethod : " + req);
            }

            for (String string : mappingValues) {
                System.out.println("mappingValues : " + string);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

but i get this exception :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI.createRequisition()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
    at com.hexgen.reflection.WebAPITest.main(WebAPITest.java:12)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java : accessing annotations through reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286998/java-accessing-annotations-through-reflection)

Comment: Denis, I have tried the above one first before asking question here after which only i have asked here. :)

Comment: then it would've been best if you included what you've tried and what errors you got straight away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are trying to get the `RequestMapping` annotation, and it can be placed at a class or a method, see both uses below:

For a class `YourClass`:

```
Class<YourClass> clazz = YourClass.class;
RequestMapping clazzRequestMappingAnnotation = clazz.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
RequestMethod[] methods = clazzRequestMappingAnnotation.method();
String[] mappingValues = clazzRequestMappingAnnotation.value();
```

For a method `methodName` at a class `YourClass`:

```
Class<YourClass> clazz = YourClass.class;
Method method = clazz.getMethod("methodName");
RequestMapping methodRequestMappingAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
RequestMethod[] methods = methodRequestMappingAnnotation.method();
String[] mappingValues = methodRequestMappingAnnotation.value();
```

Comment: Please have a look at my EDIT? Still could not solve the issue

Comment: Yes i have resolved, forgot to pass the arguments while creating method

Comment: are you there ? when i use this i get request method : POST for (RequestMethod req : methods) {
    System.out.println("RequestMethod : " + req);
   }

Comment: but if i directly print like `System.out.println("RequestMethod : " + methods);` then i get `[Lorg.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;@1f3785d3`. how to convery this to desired request method like GET or POST ??

Comment: `methods` is an array of `RequestMethod` (which is an `Enum`). To print them, you can use `for (RequestMethod requestMethod : methods) { System.out.println("RequestMethod: "+requestMethod.name()); }` . Let me know if it works.

Comment: yup if i use for loop it prints the desired value, my scansion is different and i have to pass the request method.

Comment: Hm, I didn't understand, did it work? You can get the value (the `String` `"GET"` or `"POST"`) of one specific method with: `String strMethod = methods[0].name();`

Answer (score 1):

If this annotation is on a class (eg: `Test`) then

```
RequestMapping a = Test.class.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
RequestMethod m = a.getMethod();
```