# Get annotation on a specific object in the class

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have the following class in java:

```java
public class Classic {
    @Annotate1(location="foo", name="bar")
    public final Comp1 comp1 = new Comp1();

    @Annotate2(member="blessed")
    public final Comp2 comp2 = new Comp2();
}
```

Now in a separate class, I have access to objects of `Classic`, `Comp1` and `Comp2`. At the same place, I don't have knowledge of the names of the fields in `Classic.`
How can I get the Annotation for `comp1` and `comp2` objects?

Comment: Through reflection, you can get the `Field`s of a `Class` and get any `Annotation` on each `Field`.

Comment: To clarify @SotiriosDelimanolis's point, an annotation can't go on an object. It can go on a class or a field (or methods, or other such things) but not on an object.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286998/java-accessing-annotations-through-reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to get you started:

```
public class Classic {
    @Annotate1(location = "foo", name = "bar")
    public final Comp1 comp1 = new Comp1();

    @Annotate2(member = "blessed")
    public final Comp2 comp2 = new Comp2();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class clazz = Classic.class;
        for(Field field: clazz.getDeclaredFields()){

            if(field.isAnnotationPresent(Annotate1.class)){
                Annotate1 annotate1 = field.getAnnotation(Annotate1.class);
                System.out.println(annotate1.name());
            }else if(field.isAnnotationPresent(Annotate2.class)){
                Annotate2 annotate2 = field.getAnnotation(Annotate2.class);
                System.out.println(annotate2.member());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you're making your own annotations make sure they are set to be retained at runtime:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)  //Important
public @interface Annotate1 {

    String name();

    String location();

}
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for the edit! I make that mistake all of the time.  I really need to break that habit.

Comment: LOL, I got your back.