# How to find which class or method contain specific annotation?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Suppose we are having a class with separate user define annoation in same package like

```
@One

class A
{


}

@Two

class B
{


}

@One

class C
{


}
```

How will I find which class is using `@one` annotation and which `@Two`?

**OR**

We are having a class in which methods are annotated and i want to retrieve which annotation is having which annotation

like :

```
class A
{

  @two

  public method1()
  {

  }

  @one

  public method2()
  {

  }

  @two

  public method3()
  {

  }

 }
```

I am using core java reflection and annotations.

Any other idea to do something like this will be appreciated.
Any help will be appreciated

This is my trail code which is not working. If u have some new way than guide me.

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

@GUI
public class Demo{


   public static void example() {
       Demo ob = new Demo();

      try {
         Class c = ob.getClass();

         // get the method example
         Method m = c.getMethod("example");

         // get the annotations
         Annotation[] annotation = m.getAnnotations();

         // print the annotation
         for (int i = 0; i < annotation.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(annotation[i]);
         }
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException exc) {
         exc.printStackTrace();
      }
   }


   public static void show()
   {
       java.lang.annotation.Annotation[] annotations = null;
    try {
        annotations = Class.forName("Demo").getAnnotations();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     //prints [@java.lang.Deprecated()]
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(annotations));
   }

   public static void myMeth() {
       Demo ob = new Demo();

        try {
          Annotation annos[] = ob.getClass().getAnnotations();

          System.out.println("All annotations for Meta2:");
          for (Annotation a : annos)
            System.out.println(a);

          Method m = ob.getClass().getMethod("myMeth");
          annos = m.getAnnotations();

          System.out.println("All annotations for myMeth:");
          for (Annotation a : annos)
            System.out.println(a);

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException exc) {
          System.out.println("Method Not Found.");
        }
   }


   public static void main(String args[]) {
      example();
       show();
       myMeth();
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you even searched SO? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286998/java-accessing-annotations-through-reflection

Comment: It is not working for me. Do you have another solution

Comment: Please append your annotation processing code above.

Comment: Please find the appended code

Answer (score 0):

Once you have found the annotation on the Class or Method, you can check the type of the annotation.

```
Annotation a = .....
if (a.annotationType().equals(GUI.class)) {
    System.out.println("Found");
}
```

EDIT: Full working class

```
@Deprecated
public class Demo {
    public static void example() {
        try {
            Class c = Demo.class;
            // get the annotations
            Annotation[] classAnnotations = c.getAnnotations();
            // print Class annotation
            for (int i = 0; i < classAnnotations.length; i++) {
                if (classAnnotations[i].annotationType().equals(Deprecated.class)) {
                    System.out.println("Class Annotation: " + classAnnotations[i].annotationType());
                }
            }

            // get the method show
            Method m = c.getMethod("show");
            Annotation[] methodAnnotations = m.getDeclaredAnnotations();
            // print Methods annotation
            for (int i = 0; i < methodAnnotations.length; i++) {
                if (methodAnnotations[i].annotationType().equals(Deprecated.class)) {
                    System.out.println("Method Annotation: " + methodAnnotations[i].annotationType());
               }
            }

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Deprecated
    public static void show()
    {
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        example();
    }
}
```

Comment: But want i want to retrieve all the annotation present in class and perform operation according to selected annotation.

Comment: Through this i am finding annotation present at class level only for one class i am having many testcases

Comment: Suppose i am having a class testcases having GUI ,Functional and others these three categories of testcase. i want to found method or class according to category and execute that method or class which ever is possible.

Comment: I saw in your code you are able to find all annotations on Class and Methods.  This solution will allow you to identify which annotation is present.  Once you identify the method, you can use `method.invoke....` to execute the method.  You can also create a new object of a class using reflection.  For example, `Object instance = Class.forName("MyClass").newInstance();`

Comment: My myMeth method is giving annoation present on given method like in my case it is myMeth.  But I may have multiple method with multiple annoatation that i will not declare for each method.

Comment: @AnuragMishra I have added the working example to the original answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this will not work with if we are having user define annotations and if you try this with other java annotation  like @Resource than it is not working.

Comment: The annotation `@Resource` is working for me.  Unless I see your class, it is hard to find out the issue you are having. Please post your class.

Comment: I have added my example to your answer

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution of this problem by some different ways:-

Create a user define annotation

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TestAnnotation
{
    String testText();
}
```

Create a class which is using this annoation

```
public class TestClass {
      @TestAnnotation(testText="arg")
        public void doSomething(){ 
          System.out.println("kaam banta arg 1111");
      }

      @TestAnnotation(testText="anu")
        public void doSomething1(){
          System.out.println("Calling ANU");


      }

      @TestAnnotation(testText="arg")
        public void doSomething2(){
          System.out.println("kaam banta arg 22222");
      }
```

Create a class with this logic

```
public class ClassesfromPackage {

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {

        try {

            for (Method method : TestClass.class.getMethods())
            {
                if (method.isAnnotationPresent((Class<? extends Annotation>) TestAnnotation.class))
                {
                    TestAnnotation ta = method.getAnnotation(TestAnnotation.class);
                    if(ta.testText().contains("anu"))
                    {
                    String aMethod = method.getName();
                    System.out.println(aMethod);
                    Object iClass = TestClass.class.newInstance();
                    Class params[] = {};
                    Object paramsObj[] = {};
                    Method thisMethod = TestClass.class.getDeclaredMethod(aMethod, params);
                    // call the method
                    thisMethod.invoke(iClass, paramsObj);
                    }
                    /*else
                    {
                        String aMethod = method.getName();
                        Object iClass = TestClass.class.newInstance();
                        Class params[] = {};
                        System.out.println("Inside Else");
                        Object paramsObj[] = {};
                        Method thisMethod = TestClass.class.getDeclaredMethod(aMethod, params);
                        // call the method
                        thisMethod.invoke(iClass, paramsObj);
                    }*/
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
}
```

This is calling the respective method.

But a new problem rises that How to call JUNIT @Test annoated method in TestClass where we are invoking its methods like dosomething1.

Waiting for answer.