# Reflection can not find annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I can not get annotations of beans, i'm working with spring framework:

Runnable test class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PropertyDescriptor pd = BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptor(Test.class,"foo");
        Method m=pd.getReadMethod();
        System.out.println(m.isAnnotationPresent(Annot.class));
    }

}
```

Bean class;

```
public class Test {

    private String foo;

        @Annot
        public String getFoo() {
            return foo;
        }

        public void setFoo(String foo) {
            this.foo = foo;
        }

    }
```

Annotation class:

```
public @interface Annot {

}
```

The main class get "false" as output... why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java : accessing annotations through reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286998/java-accessing-annotations-through-reflection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your annotation is missing a runtime retention policy.

Do the following:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Annot {

}
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3108036/2504224) SO question which explains the default policy and what it does.
To sum the information in that answer, the default retention policy is `CLASS`, which means that the annotation is in the bytecode, but does not have to be retained when the class is loaded